# How can I disable iStop in a 2009 Mazda 3?

Tags: mazda, mazda-3

I purchased my 2009 Mazda 3 new with a 2L petrol engine, manual transmission, and iStop.

I would like to disable this iStop feature completely. Is there any DIY way to do this, or must I take it back to the dealer?

Comment: Take it to the dealer.

Comment: @Moab - [The dealer won't do it.](http://mazda3revolution.com/forums/2014-2017-mazda-3-skyactiv-how-guides/110642-how-disable-i-stop-permanently-10-seconds.html#post1454754)

Comment: Then he would need to take it to an aftermarket mazda tuner that has software that can do it.

Comment: For what it's worth I'm a programmer with experience in embedded systems so my definition of DIY may be slightly more expansive here. If it's all proprietary protocols and software I'm not going to try reverse engineering that (though others perhaps have already...?).

Comment: Forget it. I´m a programmer too, but those car-computers usually have some flash memory you can only access with custom protocol and then, one bit turns off the stop-feature and the next one may turn off ESP or contain the fuel mapping you´ll mess up. There out to be some tuner in your area who can do the mod for a few bucks.

Comment: @rcampbell It's possible to do this on a 2015 mazda 6, see: https://no-cache.net/projects/mazda-how-to-disable-istop/